# Separate date from time in EXCEL column

Tags: vba, excel

This question might seem very simple but honestly, I'm not being able to solve it.

I have like 25000 rows of data and I want to filter it by time. However, I do not have a column with just "time", I have it with "date and time":

[image: Date column]

As you can imagine, its quite hard to filter all the occurences that happened during 1 hour... Per example, I filtered and tried to select the rows with "07:" but of course it gets me also some rows that are like "12:07:52" and the list is too big to select them manually. I tried to create another column and change the type of the cell, but it was also useless.

Comment: another option might be to change the column's Custom Number Format to "h" so that only the hours show up in the filter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options:  The `[hour]` function or the `[text]` function (with "hh" as the format).  Either will get you where you need to be, I think.

https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-hour-function
https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/text.php

Comment: Thank you, the [hour] function is not working but the [text] solution worked perfectly! :)

Answer (score 2):

To separate the time in a new column, use this formula in that new column:

```
=MOD(A2,1)
```

And format it as Time.  This will strip off the date portion of the value.

To get just the date, without any time attached use:

```
=INT(A2)
```

And format as date.

To excel a date time is a number.  The number of days since 1/1/1900.  Time is a decimal part of one day.

By stripping either the integers or the decimals we can isolate the date from the time and vice versa.

Comment: Similarly, to get just the date portion, use `=FLOOR(A2, 1)` or `=FLOOR.MATH(A2)`.

Comment: @Phylogenesis I prefer `=INT(A2)` for just the date.  it is shorter.

Comment: Wow, I did not know about that function. Why on earth does Excel have two functions that do exactly the same thing?

Comment: @Phylogenesis because they are meant for different uses, we just bastardized them for our use, exploiting loop holes.

Comment: I guess every day really is a school day.

Comment: @Phylogenesis FLOOR and INT do not return the same values on Negative numbers !

Comment: Hahaha thank you so much for the lesson guys :)

Comment: @PatrickHonorez I thought that might be the case and checked. They both work exactly the same in Excel 2016, even with negative numbers.